# debugging typescript tests in VS code

Tags: typescript, debugging, testing, visual-studio-code, testcafe

I am following steps from here http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/debug-in-visual-studio-code.html to debug testcafe **typescript** tests in VS code but for some reason, it is not working for debugging typescript tests. any idea on this?

Comment: Could you please share more details about the issue? What kind of problem is it (the browser doesn't start, the browser hangs, breakpoints don't work, etc.)? Also, could you provide your operating system, Node.js and TestCafe versions, your `launch.json` configuration file and your test file?

Comment: @AndreyBelym thanks for your comment i double checked my config and its because of wrong 'program' value in launch.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the problem and its with my launch.json file

for **program** parameter in launch.json previously i am using `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/testcafe"` changing it to `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe.js"` worked and debugging is working now.